# как добавить параметр чтобы логотип logo.png добавился в видео

Tags: ffmpeg

У меня есть строка параметров:
{
  "Input": "D:\folder\StockFiles",
  "Output": "D:\folder\MP4",
  "Ffmpeg": "D:\folder\Temp\FfmpegEncoder\ffmpeg.exe",
  "logo.png": "D:\folder\Temp\FfmpegEncoder\logo.png",
  "Parameters": " -crf 25 -level 3.1 -tune film -filter:v scale=640:360 -sws_flags lanczos -vbr 5 ",
  "DefaultFormat": "mp4"
}

понимаю что в Parameters надо добавить кусок кода logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10"

но куда добавить не пойму. все время выскакивает ошибка.
logo.png - это файл, такого же размера как и видео, с прозрачным фоном, с небольшим непрозрачным логотипом справа внизу

подскажите как правильно должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Когда то использовал следующий скрипт:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -s 720x432 -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-140:120 [out]" -f mp4 -vcodec h264 -threads 0 -r 25 -g 50 -b:v 1000k -bt 500k -acodec mp3 -ar 44100 -ab 64k output.mp4 -y
```

Лого, исходное видео и скрипт лежат в одной папке.